# Would all my Stack Exchange community profiles be used for Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

When a person is a part of multiple communities on Stack Exchange, would the reputation gained in all those communities attribute Stack Overflow Careers or does it only concern the account on Stack Overflow?

Comment: You can choose which communities your reputation count is shown from in your profile.

Comment: @Pekka웃: And would those chosen communities contribute towards your career options?

Comment: Contribute in which way? As far as I know, your reputation count doesn't give you any more options on Careers.SO, not even SO reputation. It's just that potential employers get to see it, if you so choose. That *could* possibly, maybe, give you an advantage over any similar competing candidates in the eyes of that potential employer.

Comment: Thanks, @Pekka웃,  this detail is exactly what I wanted. It would be nicer if you could include this as an answer so I can up-vote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get to choose which of your communities you want to be featured on your Careers page.

[image]

If you choose a community, your reputation level in that community will also be displayed.

Other than that, reputation does not, as far as I know, give you any more options, or any competitive advantage on Careers (beyond how a potential employer may be interpreting your rep count in a specific community.)